Why is my JMeter view results tree only shows the request as negative numbers such as -269, -270 after recording a script and executing it?
I am new to JMeter and and trying to learn how to record jmeter test script, i have followed the official step by step from this website
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html
from the videos i watched from youtube it should'nt have captured the requests as -269, and so on here is the screenshot of the results tree along with others
I expect it to name the labels correctly and not just negative numbers, is this normal?

It's up to you how to name the transaction/sampler.
JMeter gives you the possibility to provide transaction names:

As per HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder documentation

Prefix/Transaction name Add a prefix to sampler name during recording (Prefix mode). Or replace sampler name by user chosen name (Transaction name)
Naming scheme Select the naming scheme for sampler names during recording. Default is Transaction name
Naming format If Use format string is selected as naming scheme, a freestyle format can be given. Placeholders for the transaction name, scheme, host, port, path and counter can be given by #{name}, #{scheme}, #{host}, #{port}, #{path}, #{url} and #{counter}. A simple format could be "#{name}-#{counter}", which would be equivalent to the numbered default naming scheme. For more complex formatting Java formatting for MessageFormat can be used, as in "#{counter,number,000}: #{name}-#{path}", which would print the counter filled with up to three zeroes. Note that scheme is called protocol in the sampler GUI and host is called domain. Default is an empty string.

Also be aware of an easier way of recording a JMeter test script: JMeter Chrome Extension, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies, certificates, transaction names and so on.
